# Make input accept one letter with regex and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, input

I have this:

```
$('.onealphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g{1},'') ); }
);
```

where what I hope it would do is that it allows the user to input *only one* letter in an input field. It accepts only letters for now, but I cannot make it to allow only one letter (and have searched dozens of SO answers). Any ideas?

<kbd>[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ka52kdLv/13/)</kbd>

Comment: also `maxlength=1`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I think this could be posted as an answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the first letter of the input and replace everything by its value.

```js
$('.onealphaonly').bind('keyup', function() { 
    const node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/^([a-zA-Z]).*/g, '$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="onealphaonly"/>
```

Comment: Regex101 says: `{1} Quantifier — Matches exactly one time (meaningless quantifier)`.

Comment: @gsamaras You're right, the `{1}` is completely useless, sorry about that. Post edited :)

Comment: Thank you Erazihel. Do you think my question was so bad to get a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your regex. It should be formatted as `/pattern/flags`. Here is a regex that works: `node.val().replace(/^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+/g, '$1')`. There are many ways of crafting a regex that'll do the job, however why don't you use the following instead:

```
node.val().substr(0, 1);
```

Also, you may have better success by also checking if the length of the value is greater than one and using `e.preventDefault()` like so:

```
if (node.val().length >= 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ka52kdLv/14/

Comment: Thanks Adam for the answer and the upvote!